# Duda con ciclo while & if

Tags: c#, condiciones, while

El ejercicio pide ingresar valores mayores a 0 y devolver el número máximo y mínimo ingresados. No sé si está bien lo que estoy haciendo o interpretando mal la consigna. Yo la entiendo así: de los valores ingresados, informar cuál es el mínimo y cuál el máximo.

Entonces, resolví de la manera que muestra la imagen. Si cuando el primer Console.Write me pide el primer valor y pongo el mayor y en el segundo Console.Write ingreso el menor, el Console.WriteLine fuera del bucle me los devuelve correctamente. Pero si hago a la inversa (primero ingreso el menor y segundo el mayor), me devuelve, ´por ej., "El máximo es 11 y el mínimo es 12".

¿Hay alguna manera (en principio básica, pues ese es mi nivel) de que devuelva siempre el máximo primero y el segundo siempre mínimo?

UPDATE: lo que hice en principio (quizás hay una mejor forma) es forzar un if fuera del ciclo "if (minimo1 > maximo1)" devuelve en el orden adecuado.

Saludos.

CÓDIGO:

//7. Ingresar valores mayores a cero y devolver finalmente el máximo y el mínimo.

```
int b3 = 0, minimo1 = 0, maximo1 = 0, valor1;

Console.Write("7.Ingrese un valor mayor a 0: ");
valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Ingrese otro valor mayor a 0: ");
valor1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (valor != 0)
{
    if (b3 == 0)
    {
        maximo1 = valor;
        minimo1 = valor1;
        b3 = 1;
    }
    else if (valor > maximo1)
    {
        maximo1 = valor;
    }
    else if (valor1 > minimo1)
    {
        minimo1 = valor1;
    }

    Console.Write("Ingrese un valor mayor a 0: ");
    valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Ingrese otro valor mayor a 0: ");
    valor1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

if (minimo1 > maximo1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El máximo es {minimo1} y el mínimo es {maximo1}.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El máximo es {maximo1} y el mínimo es {minimo1}.");
}
```

Comment: Cambia esa imagen por código, así podremos ayudarte más fácil.

Comment: Agregado, gracias

Comment: Hola Franco. ¿Por qué motivo utilizas un bucle while? Ýo haría una serie de comparaciones entre números (con un if/else if/else bastaría), y luego los mostraría por pantalla. Comprobaría que los dos números son mayores que 0 y luego realizaría el if/else if/else. Aunque también podrías usar un operador ternario. Un saludo

Comment: @jakintsuIheslari porque el ejercicio pide que sea con while. La idea es que ir ingresando números y que finalmente se muestre el mayor y el mínimo de todos los ingresados

Comment: No entiendo porque pides dos valores... con pedir uno y compararlo con el max y min alcanza... luego, solo imprimes max y min resultantes.. para que quieres el ultimo if... de paso, tu if para el minimo esta mal...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias. Lo que sucede es que el max y min están inicializados en 0, la idea es ir reemplazando ese 0 por el max y min

Comment: @Franco revisa lo que puse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes dijo "Jack el destripador", no puedo leer la consigna, pero estoy bastante seguro que lo que se te pide, es ingresar una cantidad "x" (por eso el `while`) de números, y determinar cuales, entre los ingresados, son el menor y el mayor.
Podrías empezar pidiendo la cantidad de números a ingresar, con ese valor controlas el `while`.
Seguidamente pides el primer número, e instancias **minimo1** y **maximo1** con su valor.
Entras al `while`, vuelves a pedir un número y con los `else if` que tienes (el `if` está sobrando) vas actualizando el valor de **minimo1** y **maximo1**, según corresponda, para luego, al salir del `while`, imprimirlos.
Nota: se sobreentiende que debes cambiar el primer `else if` por `if`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. La consigna es "Ingresar valores mayores a 0 y devolver finalmente el máximo y el mínimo. Lo hice siguiendo los pasos que me mencionabas, no estoy seguro de haberlo hecho bien!

Comment: puedes publicar lo que has hecho como respuesta, y lo verificamos.

Comment: Listo! Creo que lo hice mal

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = -1;
int min = Int32.MaxValue;
int num = -1;

while(num != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un número:");

    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if(num > 0)
    {
        if(num > max)
        {
            max = num;
        }

        if(num < min)
        {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El número ingresado debe ser mayor a 0. Ingrese un nuevo número:");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Número menor: {0}", min);
Console.WriteLine("Número mayor: {0}", max);
```

**Se declaran 3 variables**:

**max**: Almacenará el mayor número introducido. Se inicializa en **0**.

**min**: Almacenará el menor número introducido. Se inicializa con el número más grande que admite el tipo de datos **int**.

**num**: Almacena el número introducido por el usuario, sobre el cual se harán todas las comprobaciones pertinentes.

Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo while**, el cual se ejecutará mientras el usuario no introduzca el valor **0**. Dentro del **ciclo while** se le pide al usuario que introduzca un número el cual será guardado en la **variable num**, se pregunta si es mayor que **0**, ya que solo se admiten números positivos, de cumplirse esta condición se pregunta si **num** es mayor que **max**, de serlo se actualiza el valor de **max** con el valor de **num**. Posteriormente se pregunta si **num** es menor que **min**, de serlo se actualiza el valor de **min**, en la próxima iteración **num** se comparará con los nuevos valores de las **variables max** y **min**, y se volverán a actualizar de cumplirse la condiciones dentro del **ciclo while**, y así sucesivamente. Por último cuando se sale del **ciclo while**, se imprime el valor de la **variable min** y el valor de la **variable max**.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pregunta, ¿por qué el min lo declaraste con el máximo valor?

Comment: Al min se le da un valor muy grande para que en las comparaciones este valor vaya decreciendo, es decir inicializa con un valor muy grande, y este valor se va reduciendo poco a poco a medida que haces las comparaciones. Con max ocurre al revés, se inicializa con un valor pequeño, que irá aumentando poco a poco en las comparaciones. @Franco